# Pandas merge a "%Y%M%D" date column with a "%H:%M:%S" time column

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a `dataframe` with a column composed by `date` object and a column composed by `time` object.
I have to merge the two columns.

Personally, I think it is so ugly the following solution.
Why I have to cast to `str`?
I crafted my solution based [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49668702/6290211)

```
#importing all the necessary libraries 
import pandas as pd 
import datetime

#I have only to create a Minimal Reproducible Example
time1 = datetime.time(3,45,12)
time2 = datetime.time(3,49,12)
date1 = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17)
date2 = datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 17)
date_dict= {"time1":[time1,time2],"date1":[date1,date2]}

df=pd.DataFrame(date_dict)

df["TimeMerge"] = pd.to_datetime(df.date1.astype(str)+' '+df.time1.astype(str))
```

Comment: i agree it would be nice if they overloaded `+` for `date` and `time`, but your current `str`/`to_datetime()` code is the fastest way to do it (even if it looks uglier)

Comment: if your real data is coming from a csv, [`pd.read_csv(..., parse_dates=[['date1','time1']])`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44920602/13138364) would probably be the "prettiest" and fastest option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can let pandas handle this for us and use `DataFrame.apply` and `datetime.datetime.combine` like this:

```
df["TimeMerge"] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.datetime.combine(row.date1, row.time1), axis=1)
```

---

Although the following approach is more explicit and might therefore be more readable if you're not familiar with `DataFrame.apply`, I would strongly recommend the first approach.

You could also manually map `datetime.datetime.combine` over a zip object of `date1` and `time1`:

```
def combine_date_time(d_t: tuple) -> datetime.datetime:
    return datetime.datetime.combine(*d_t)

df["TimeMerge"] = pd.Series(map(combine_date_time, zip(df.date1, df.time1)))
```

You can also inline it as an anonymous lambda function:

```
df["TimeMerge"] = pd.Series(map(lambda d_t: datetime.datetime.combine(*d_t), zip(df.date1, df.time1)))
```

This is handy for simple operations, but I would advise against this one-liner in this case.

---

By the way, [the answer your were looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39474812/9173379) can also be found under [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17978092/9173379).

Comment: "can and should" seems too conclusive though. `apply(axis=1)` is usually the slowest option. in this case, it's 2x slower than `pd.to_datetime()` at 200 rows, 3x slower at 2K rows, 3.5x slower at 2M rows.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I was expecting `df.apply` to be faster than that. I reduced it to *"can"*.

Comment: Thank you @riskypenguin I missed the specific answer :)